# How to update nativescript cli

Tags: nativescript, npm-install, nativescript-cli

Nativescript 5 is out and I am trying to update the tns version. Currently it tns --version shows as 4.3.2.

I followed all the steps in https://docs.nativescript.org/releases/upgrade-instructions but it still gives me the version as 4.3.2.

How can I upgrade nativescript-cli so that tns --version shows me the latest version.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I did following to reflect the update Nativescript cli. You should only follow this when **npm install -g nativescript@latest** doesn't reflect update the cli. You can check that using **tns --version** before and after.

1. Uninstall current nativescript cli using **npm uninstall -g nativescript**
2. Delete the existing tns command manuall if it still exist on your machine.
3. Install the latest Nativescript cli using **npm install -g nativescript@latest**
4. tns --version should now show the latest version.

Comment: How do I delete the existing tns command manually if it still exist on my machine?

Comment: Search for the tns.exe file on your machine and delete it. You can also check all locations under your PATH variable.

Comment: I succeeded doing so. I am on Linux so I searched for tns and deleted it everywhere. Thanks a lot

Comment: Good to hear that!

Answer (score 3):

How I did update tns:

1. run cmd as administrator (you using windows as i read above in one of comments)
2. (optional) run `npm view nativescript version` to check latest aveilable on npm
3. run `tns install -g nativescript`
4. restart `cmd`
5. run `tns --version` - hopefully you will see `5.0.0`

hope this helps.

Btw, you might need to run some additional commands for your projects if you already added `platforms`
`tns platform remove {platform}`

`tns platform add {platform}`, where `{platform}` is `android` or `ios`

...also, you might run `tns doctor` after upgrading as I noticed it broke my other components like `choco`.

Comment: I think u meant ```npm install -g nativescript``` instead of ```tns install -g nativescript```